# Unity How do you rotate an object with a rigidbody so it's facing the it is traveling

Tags: c#, unity

I would like to know how i can rotate an object with an rigidbody so it's facing the way it's traveling.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to get the direction you are traveling in:

```
Vector2 direction = rigidBody2D.velocity.normalize();
```

Then you want to get the angle of this direction:

```
float ang = Vector2.Angle(rigidBody2D.transform.position, direction);
Vector3 cross = Vector3.Cross(rigidBody2D.transform.position, direction);

if (cross.z > 0)
    ang = 360 - ang;
```

Then you can use MoveRotation to adjust your rigidBody's new direction:

```
Quaternion q = Quaternion.Euler(ang);
rigidBody2D.MoveRotation(q);
```

I didn't test any of this.

Comment: nice @jon ... it's the simple stuff that I often trip up on lol

Comment: lol @Wardy, this wasn't your question though :P

Comment: Yeh I just liked how you went ... "oh it's easy ..." and i'm sat here thinking ... aww this is gonna be a tough one lol

Comment: I'm sorry i didn't specify it in the question but how would you do this in a 3d space with a normal rigidbody and not a rigidbody2D.

Comment: Same thing, except to get the angle you would do:   Vector3.Angle(rigidBody.transform.position, direction);